# Highlighted items in multi-selection file-chooser are dynamically changed while scrolling listview

Tags: android

I have selected set of items from my sdcard folder using multi-selection file-chooser.It returns exactly selected values but the selection highlighted items (using colors) are dynamically changed while scrolling list-view..can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Here i have added my file-chooser class and adapter class..

```
public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

private File currentDir;
private FileArrayAdapter adapter;

private Bundle selectedfiles;
String selectedFileAbspath;
ArrayList<String> images_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean is_multiple;
Button file_upload;
Integer val;
Pattern fileExtnPtrn;;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    is_multiple = this.getIntent().getExtras()
            .getBoolean("is_multiple", false);
    val = this.getIntent().getExtras()
            .getInt("value");

    if (is_multiple) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.file_chooser_list);
        file_upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.file_upload);
        file_upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(selectedfiles.size()!=0)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("selected_files", selectedfiles);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();                   
                }
                else
                {
                    showDialog("Please Choose Atleast one File");
                }


            }
        });
    }
    currentDir = new File("/sdcard/");
    selectedfiles = new Bundle();
    fill(currentDir);
}
private void fill(File f)
{
    File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
     this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
     List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
     List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
     try
     {
         for(File ff: dirs)
         { 
            Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
            DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
            if(ff.isDirectory())
            {                   
                File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles(); 
                int buf = 0;
                if(fbuf != null)
                { 
                    buf = fbuf.length;
                } 
                else buf = 0; 
                String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                if(buf == 0) 
                    num_item = num_item + " item";
                else 
                    num_item = num_item + " items";

                //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(),num_item,date_modify,ff.getAbsolutePath(),"directory_icon")); 
            }
            else
            {

                fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(),ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(),"file_icon"));
            }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {    

     }
     Collections.sort(dir);
     Collections.sort(fls);
     dir.addAll(fls);
     if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
         dir.add(0,new Item("..","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"directory_up"));
     adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
     this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
    if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")||o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
            currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
    }
    else
    {
        onFileClick(o,v);
    }
}
private void onFileClick(Item o,View v)
{
    selectedFileAbspath = currentDir.toString() + "/" + o.getName();

    RelativeLayout list_item=(RelativeLayout) v;

    if(is_multiple)
    {
                        if(validateFileExt(selectedFileAbspath))
                        {
                            if (selectedfiles.containsKey(selectedFileAbspath)) 
                            {
                            selectedfiles.remove(selectedFileAbspath);
                            list_item.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));               
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                            selectedfiles.putString(selectedFileAbspath, "1");
                            list_item.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            showDialog("please select valid image file");
                        }

    }
    else 
    {
        if(validateFileExt(selectedFileAbspath))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("GetPath", currentDir.toString());
            intent.putExtra("GetFileName", o.getName());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
private boolean validateFileExt(String fileName)
{       

    fileExtnPtrn = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png))$)");

    Matcher mtch = fileExtnPtrn.matcher(fileName);
    return mtch.matches();
}

 private void showDialog(String string) 
 {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle(string);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Okay",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

}

**Adapter class**

public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
private Context c;
private int id;
private List<Item>items;

public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    c = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = objects;
}
public Item getItem(int i)
 {
     return items.get(i);
 }
 @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = convertView;
           if (v == null) {
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               v = vi.inflate(id, null);
           }

           /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
        //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

           final Item o = items.get(position);
           if (o != null) {
                   TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                   TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                   TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                   /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                    ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                    String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                   if(t1!=null)
                    t1.setText(o.getName());
                   if(t2!=null)
                        t2.setText(o.getData());
                   if(t3!=null)
                        t3.setText(o.getDate());

           }
           return v;
   }
```

}

Comment: please share the code for the adapter and listview

Answer (score 0):

your problem in getItem method in ListAdapter of List

Comment: No i'm getting the values correctly..having problem in selection change(highlighted colors moved to next items) while scrolling down/up the listview..but values remains same in list.

Comment: can you give full code of your programm? with adapter

Comment: ok) i recommend you read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) and [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/).
you can use standart android tools for multiselecting without manual modifications)

Comment: if there are problems i can help write code for you

Comment: i tried alot but didn't work.if u can edit my code means too helpful for me.or if u know any other ways to do multi-selection with highlight items be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: so give me your github project)

Comment: sorry i don't have github project.

Answer (score 0):

try this adapter) you must determine all elements of each item in your case)

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

private Context c;
private int id;
private List<Item>items;

public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    c = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = objects;
}
public Item getItem(int i)
 {
     return items.get(i);
 }
 @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View v = convertView;
           if (v == null) {
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               v = vi.inflate(id, null);
           }

           /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
                    TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                   TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                   TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                   /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                    ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                    String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);

                   if(t1!=null)
                    t1.setText(o.getName());
                   if(t2!=null)
                        t2.setText(o.getData());
                   if(t3!=null)
                        t3.setText(o.getDate());

           return v;
   }
}
```